# Dual Lorentz characterization of $L^q$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to do Exercise A.4 of Terence Tao's book [Nonlinear dispersive equations: local and global analysis](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/chapter.pdf). The exercise is on p.342 in Appendix A. The problem statement is:

> Let $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for some $1<q<\infty$.  Show that
>   $$
> \|f\|_{L^q}^q \sim_q \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{k(1-q)}
> \sup_{E_k} \left|\int_{E_k} f(x)\,dx\right|^q
> $$
>   where $E_k$ ranges over bounded open sets of measure $2^k$.

The hint is to use the rearrangement 
$f^*(x) := \inf\{\alpha : |\{|f|>\alpha\}|<x\}$, show that 
$\sup_{E_k} \left|\int_{E_k} f(x)\,dx\right| \sim \int_0^{2^k} f^*(t)\,dt$,
and then decompose the interval $[0,2^k]$ dyadically.

So far I have done the first part, but I have no idea how decomposing $[0,2^k]$
dyadically will help me.  I do know, however, that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|^q\,dx = \int_0^\infty (f^*(t))^q\,dt,
$$
so an estimate of the form
$$
\left(\int_0^{2^k} f^*(t)\,dt\right)^q \sim_q 
2^{k(q-1)}\int_{2^{k-1}}^{2^k} (f^*(t))^q\,dt
$$
would suffice.  However, it is easy to construct counterexamples where the above fails.  What other approach might work here?

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, and would appreciate any advice.  Thanks!